# Can't open mov files in QuickTime, but can do it in VLC

Tags: video, file-conversion, encoding, mov

After reinstalling the operating system (OS X EL Capitan) I can't open video files in .mov format. I can open them using VLC but I can't open them in QuickTime and Adobe Premiere - what could be wrong? Maybe I need some codecs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what Google says:

> According to the info in Apple official site, QuickTime does support MOV files. However, MOV is a multimedia container file that contains one or more tracks, each of which stores a particular type of data: audio, video, effects, or text (e.g. for subtitles).

So it could be possible that a part of the .mov file may not be supported by the QuickTime player. In this case, I would suggest you to convert the file to a .mp4 or a QuickTime compatible .mov format using a third party application.

Comment: Could you advise me a converter to do that? MPEG Streamclip, which I thought was the most universal converter can't open these videos.

Btw, It is strange that I can open some of them but not all of them... This are videos from my camera, that have no post-processing.

Comment: I usually use Any Video Converter Lite from the App Store itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of QT? If not, install the latest version. 
MOV is a file container format. Your mov file can be encoded with different types of codecs that may be incompatible with QT. You can check the video detailed info with Mediainfo.